# Is there a smart way to superclass both UITableviewDataSource and a UICollectionViewDatasource

Tags: ios, uitableview, architecture, uicollectionview

I would like to have 1 super class for both UITableviewDataSource and UICollectionViewDatasource. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You can't superclass the built in iOS protocols. Do you mean you want to subclass them? Have one protocol that incorporates both the `UITableViewDataSource` and the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols?

Comment: Yes. Have one protocol that incorporates both the UITableViewDataSource and the UICollectionViewDataSource protocols

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your own protocol and state that the new protocol conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`. Let's call it `CombinedProtocol`. Then anything that says it implements the `CombinedProtocol` will have to implement the usual table view and collection view methods.

```
@protocol CombinedProtocol <NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource>
// add any additional methods if you want
@end
```

Comment: It's not good. I want classes that inherit from CombinedProtocol to implement UITableViewDataSource or (!!) UICollectionViewDataSource. Not both.

Comment: Ohhh. "Or" was an important word there. I don't know that there is a way to do that.